# How to execute executable file in windows and save its output using Python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to run a program which generate files while it is being watched (in order to achieve that I am using multi-threading) my code looks like that:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import os
import subprocess


def delete_folder_content():
    import shutil
    folder = r"C:/watch"
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


def watcher():
    command = r"C:/git_private/test-engineer-code-task/dist/node10-win-x64/index-win.exe -w C:/watch"
    os.system(command)


def generate():
    delete_folder_content()

    command = r"C:/git_private/test-engineer-code-task/dist/node10-win-x64/index-win.exe -g 50 -o C:/watch"

    os.system(command)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target=watcher).start()
    Thread(target=generate).start()
```

I want to be able to get the output being produced from "watcher()" method which listens to a specific folder and generate output when the folder gets populated with files.

is there a way to save to output? the output is dynamic.

Comment: Have a closer look at the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module: *"... The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes."*